# Упаковка в электроне "Убивает" основную функцию приложения

Tags: javascript, сборка, electron

Функция, находящаяся в main, работает исправно при запуске приложения через "electron main.js",
но после упаковки функция перестаёт выполняться

```
function getGoodsList() {...}
let goodsListInterval = setInterval( () => {
getGoodsList()
}, 180*1000)
```

Именно функция получения списка товаров и записи его в файл не работает в упакованном приложении. В чём может быть проблема? Спасибо!

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: вам бы там ошибку перехватить бы

Comment: Ошибка не выпадает, там функция полностью исправно работает, а в собранном приложении она просто не вызывается